# How to set current window uncancelable

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm wondering how to set showing window uncancelable in java gui. For example: when I click button window with error message (JDialog) appears and how to make this windows still visible on the screen if I click besides its dimensions? (Window must be visible until I click ex. OK button. If somewhere else it must be still visible untill click button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the JDialog `modal`.

This is an example to create a modal JDialog.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, 
                             "Click a button",
                             true);
```

More about modality [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a modal JDialog?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Window,%20java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean%29